# MEF part's dependency

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have a problem regarding MEF. In essence:

```
assembly my.main {
  class Main {
    <Import>
    Lazy<IMyType> prop;

    public static void Main(...) {
      ComposeParts(this);
      prop.DoStuff();
    }
  }
}

assembly my.interfaces {
  interface IMyType {
    void DoStuff();
  }
}

assembly my.parts {
  using 3rdParty;
  <Export>
  class MyType : IMyType {
    void DoStuff() {
      3rdParty.DoStuff();
    }
  }
}
```

Both *my.main* and *my.parts* reference *my.interfaces* assembly. In addition to that, *my.parts* assembly references a 3rd party .dll, which my other two do not. When I try to execute the above, a *CompositionException* is thrown in *Main()* when calling *prop.DoStuff()* with the message saying the class *3rdParty* could not be found.

In other words, MEF part is injected, but the dll it requires is not injected/copied.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: During the execution, is your 3rdParty assembly located in the same directory as the `my.parts` assembly file?

Comment: You have hit the spot, it is not. Adding it there solved the Exception. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) I added a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During execution, the `3rdParty` assembly file is apparently not located in the same directory as the `my.parts` assembly (or in any other location the loader probes).

Comment: Since the _my.parts_ assembly is not referenced by _my.main_ assembly, it is not included in the build process.
Therefore, _my.parts_ needs to be built separately afterwards and the content of its build output directory copied to _my.main_'s build output directory (which can be done for example by adding a couple of commands to post-build events in project's properties or by a batch script).

Comment: I see. In such cases, one must handle the assembly deployment manually.